# MySQL granting privileges to a temporary user

Tags: mysql

I have created a temporary user, which will register and only be able to view their own information. What privilege will need to be applied and on what level? (sorry for the basic question!) e.g.

```
GRANT SELECT ON userDetails.* TO 'tempAccount'@'localhost';
```

????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your needs and requirements you can grant privileges to the user. 
for example

```
GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE ON my_db.* TO 'michael'@'localhost';
```

As you have used select in your case so there fore the user has basic read privileges on the database provided.

to create a full user use below..

```
grant all on *.* to 'username'@'%' identified by 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Here user have access on all databases from all ip addresses and with grant option will authorise user to create more users.

You are in the right direction anyway.